# Quais dicionários de português (brasileiro) são confiáveis?

Tags: discussion, recursos

Lá fora, eu vejo que o dicionário mantido pela Oxford é bem consagrado.

Aqui no Brasil, eu acabo tendo essa dúvida. Até onde eu sei, nenhuma universidade tem um projeto do tipo.

Isso atrapalha um pouco, visto que gosto de contribuir na Wikipédia sobre a definição de palavras.

Comment: Por quê esta pergunta está no Meta e não no site principal?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu recomendo o Houaiss. Eu tenho a edição portuguesa (2002) que é a edição brasileira de 2001 com umas adaptaçõezinhas na grafia, colocação pronominal e pouco mais. É um dicionário muito completo—3800 páginas tamanho A4 com escrita cerrada e miudinha—com definições muito claras e exemplos. O dicionário é essencialmente um projeto brasileiro, mas mesmo as peculiaridades do português de Portugal estão bem tratadas (eu sou português), com informação se uma certa palavra ou uma certa aceção se aplica só a este ou àquele país ou só a certas regiões dum país. E se estiveres interessado na etimologia das palavras, é consensual que o Houaiss é o melhor dicionário de língua portuguesa nesse aspeto. Existe uma edição brasileira mais recente, mais compacta que a primeira.

Depois, para acesso rápido, tens vários dicionários online. Nenhum deles é tão bom como o Houaiss (também existe o Houaiss online, mas tens de pagar). Destes os meus favoritos são o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/dicion%C3%A1rio) e o [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=&t=&palavra=dicion%C3%A1rio) (ambos brasileiros). O [Priberam](http://%20%22dicion%C3%A1rio%22,%20in%20Dicion%C3%A1rio%20Priberam%20da%20L%C3%ADngua%20Portuguesa%20[em%20linha],%202008-2013,%20https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/dicion%C3%A1rio%20[consultado%20em%2031-07-2017].) talvez tenha mais palavras e aceções, mas as definições são muito resumidas, e por vezes menos esclarecedoras que quer o Aulete ou Michaelis. O Priberam é português, mas podes escolher a grafia na norma brasileira ou europeia, e indica também a grafia pré- e pós-Acordo Ortográfico. Para completar, e porque frequentemente é aconselhável consultar vários dicionários, tens a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/joia) (português, da Porto Editora) que também te indica a grafia nova e antiga (norma europeia), e o [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/joia/) (brasileiro).

Answer (score 4):

Complementando a resposta de Jacinto, há também o [TheFreeDictionary](http://pt.thefreedictionary.com/) da americana Farlex, que oferece também vários outros idiomas e dicionários (médico, legal, etc.), além de uma porção enciclopédica. E eu demorei a perceber que o [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/) oferece também dicionários de [sinônimos](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/) e [antônimos](https://www.antonimos.com.br/), além de listas de [conjugação](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/) e [dúvidas](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/).

Answer (score 1):

Como professor em formação e tradutor, recomendo o **[Dicionário Unesp do português contemporâneo](http://editoraunesp.com.br/catalogo/8571395764,dicionario-unesp-do-portugues-contemporaneo)**, organizado pelo Prof. Dr. Francisco da Silva Borba. Ao contrário de outros dicionários que, muitas vezes, são elaborados por diletantes, o **Dicionário Unesp** baseia suas acepções em um *corpus* de 90 milhões de itens lexicais, extraído do banco de dados do Laboratório de Lexicografia da Faculdade de Ciências e Letras de Araraquara/Unesp. Ele é prático e fácil de consultar porque dirige-se para qualquer pessoa, não só para estudantes do ensino básico.

Ele contém também neologismos ainda não dicionarizados (p. ex., "uspiano", denomina "estudante da USP") e abrange questões de regência nominal e verbal. É um dicionário raro no país porque registra o uso real do português contemporâneo, cada acepção é baseada em textos reais.

Outro excelente dicionário é o Michaelis, com uma longa tradição no Brasil. A versão online chamada **[Michaelis Dicionário Brasileiro da Língua Portuguesa](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/)** conta com noções gramaticais sobre o sistema ortográfico vigente, uso do hífen, acentuação gráfica, emprego das iniciais maiúsculas, entre outras.

Não recomendo a família *Aurélio* de "dicionários" porque ela já foi muito criticada a respeito de suas impropriedades na seleção das entradas (BIDERMAN, 2000). Também não utilizo o Priberam porque este é de base majoritariamente europeia. Ele pode ser útil para comparações entre as variações brasileira e lusitana.

A maioria dos dicionários tradicionais brasileiros não foi produzida por lexicógrafos, ou seja, especialistas na produção de dicionários. O *Aurélio*, embora seja muito popular, não apresenta uma organização rigorosa e contém entradas e verbetes duplicados, o que implica um inchaço de forma gráfica.

**Referência**

BIDERMAN, Maria Tereza Camargo. Aurélio: sinônimo de dicionário?. **ALFA**, São Paulo, v. 44, p. 27-55, 2000. Disponível em: https://repositorio.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/11449/107776/ISSN1981-5794-2000-44-27-55.pdf. Acesso em: 31 ago. 2018.

Comment: Não levem a mal eu dizer isto: dicionários que incluam neologismos não lexicalizados é a última coisa que a língua Portuguêsa precisa. Se formos por aí, tarda nada está a língua, e estamos nós, gentrificados - no sentido Anglo-Saxónico (pejorativo) do termo. Não haja cá perdas de identidade em matéria dicionarística.