# Should we *finally* allow reference questions on main?

Tags: discussion, recursos

**Let's migrate resources questions to the main site?**

It's been two years since this question [has been asked](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178/2764).

It has already received 11 up-votes and the highest-up-voted answer suggests

> reference questions should be: On the main site

I also strongly believe that questions such as

- [Resources for etymological research―Recursos para investigação etimológica](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288/2764)
- [Quais dicionários de português (brasileiro) são confiáveis?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/304/2764)
- [Online Portuguese dictionary with IPA transcriptions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/483/2764)

belong in the main site, since [the purpose of Meta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) is to discuss the website itself, its rules and technical aspects, and these questions are definitely not doing that.

---

[Portuguese version of the question]

**Vamos migrar as perguntas sobre recursos para o site principal?**

Já se passaram dois anos desde que essa pergunta [foi feita](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178/2764).

Ela já recebeu 11 votos positivos a resposta com mais votos positivos sugere

> perguntas sobre recursos deveriam estar: No site principal

Eu também tenho forte convicção de que questões como

- [Resources for etymological research―Recursos para investigação etimológica](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288/2764)
- [Quais dicionários de português (brasileiro) são confiáveis?](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/304/2764)
- [Online Portuguese dictionary with IPA transcriptions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/483/2764)

pertencem ao site principal, dado que o [propósito do Meta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) é discutir o próprio website, suas regras e tecnicalidades, e estas questões definitivamente não fazem isso.

Comment: We can certainly have the discussion about where new ones should go, but not even moderators are able to migrate existing questions that are as old as those are.

Comment: Ok, I dind't know that. How about the current policy, have been any question closed for being a request for reference lately?

Comment: There was one asking for Brazilian internet forums, but I'm not sure that would count. I don't see anything else within the 3-month migration window.

Comment: Yes, I think I saw it en passant and it seemed uninteresting.

Comment: I've just migrated another one of these from main to meta. I hope this does not bother anyone. We probably need a new meta-tag for these; would "recursos" work?

Comment: @tchrist What would distinguish "recursos" in the main site from "recursos" in meta?

Comment: Fair question. I have no good answer but to say that for multiple reasons resource recommendation requests aren't *usually* a good fit for main sites on the SE network, although exceptions notably exist. I do think we should find a single home for all these, but we moderators can't move old questions. However, we might be able to get JNat  or Cesar (our Portuguese and Brazilian SE Community Managers, respectively) or an SE dev to do so, though, if we could manage to reach a suitable consensus here about which way we want to go.

Comment: Sounds good, @tchrist. In Physics SE we have such a question in main - but it's community and closed and new resources are just edited into the single answer. Maybe something similar could be a good solution here too.

Comment: [It's happening](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/looking-for-one-book-for-preparation-for-the-exam-of-level-a1-in-european-portug) OMG IT'S HAPPENING!

Comment: @ANeves WTF, [this question](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/2764) has just been migrated to Meta! This question/suggestion has 5 upvotes and zero downvotes - I thought we wanted to have resources in the main page, and now it's been moved. Does the community know what it wants, and is this being respected here. It doesn't look like it.

Comment: Why did you ping *me*? I'd think you would want to talk with @tchrist about it, since [they were the one who moved it](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/6570/revisions). :)

Comment: Sorry to bother, @ANeves, I guess I just wanted to bring everyone to the conversation. :) Thanks for pinging the right person.

Comment: it's fine it's fine :) now I know to follow this :)