# Is there an European Portuguese free online dictionary that includes pronunciation?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for an online European Portuguese dictionary with pronunciation sound. Is there one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reference books on Portuguese not about the language itself.

Comment: What are the tags "recursos" and "recursos-online" for, then?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There is [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/), which has many bilingual dictionaries and offers both Brazilian and European Portuguese audios.

For instance, for "[olá](https://www.linguee.com/english-portuguese/search?source=auto&query=ol%C3%A1)".

Comment: Thank you. They don't say how to pronounce "veem" for example.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent Yes, dictionaries that include the pronunciations of conjugated verbs will be harder to find.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this pronunciation dictionary with audio in Portuguese and it seems very complete.

> https://pt.forvo.com/languages/pt/