# Let's reach a final decision on where should resources ("recursos" and "recursos-online") go?

Tags: discussion, recursos

Two years ago (2018) I've asked whether resources questions belong to the Meta or to the main site and advocated that they belong to the main site (for instance, they are not technical questions, or about Portuguese SE itself) in [this post](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/311/2764), which got 5 upvotes and zero downvotes (as it stands).

Two years before that, a [similar question](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/178/2764) had been asked, with the single (and upvoted) answer also suggesting it belongs to the main site.

Now a recent [question](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/2764) which is squarely in the "recursos online" category has been moved from the main to the Meta site.

I still believe such questions belong to the main site, possibly as community wikis, but that's beside the point: the important thing is to reach a decision and *respect* it.

So, **what do we want?**

Answer (score 1):

I have given this some thought since you posted it. <sub>(**tl;dr** in bold.)</sub>

**Disadvantages** of posting "resources" on **main** site:

- The greater number of posts.

  1. Would cause more overlap with other questions polluting search results.
  2. The above could be solved using a dedicated tag.

**Disadvantages** of posting "resources" on **meta** site:

- Less visibility for non-regular users.

  1. I don't see how this could be circumvented - most folks won't visit meta.
  2. The only way to *compensate* this would be links in answers, and signposts in comments, pointing to the meta "resource" posts.

**Advantages** of posting "resources" on **main** site:

- Any user performing a search is likely to come across the *"resource"* threads.

  1. This would invite more user to collaborate towards building and editing the resource.
  2. The above would result in a more thorough and encompassing *"resource"*.

**Advantages** of posting "resources" on **meta** site:

- Arguably those posts would become meta favorites and hallmarks.
- Inherently a *"resource"* thread models "meta", ontologically and cognitively. It is not a specific aspect in the language but an overarching category about the language. The connection of a "resource" to the language might even be only tangential.

If I had to give an opinion (analyses). I would say the **optimal solution** is 2-fold:

1. Put the **"resource" threads on main** with a proper dedicated tag.
2. Keep threads **"about resource threads" on meta**, that way any discussion on how best to maintain those threads can be separated from them, thus keeping the "rsource" itself clear of noise, while facilitating any discussion that might be necessary about a specific "resource thread".

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I think it's a good suggestion.